# ASP.NET MVC - Display Model Fields without Updating Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am currently working on a strongly-typed update view in ASP.NET MVC2.  In addition to properties the user can update, there are also some properties that the user should not be able to update, but I would like to display on the page anyway (for example, a created on date).

Here is an example of how I am displaying these non-editable fields:

```
<td>Created on:</td>
<td><%= Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.CreatedOn) %></td>
```

However, when I submit the form and then use a breakpoint on the controller method to see the model object that is being passed to the method via a POST request, the non-editable fields are set to a null or empty value (for example, the CreatedOn date is set to 1/1/0001).  The editable fields are being passed back with the correct values.  How can I display these non-editable fields while retaining the original value when I post the form back to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the original value. If you use UpdateModel (or TryUpdateModel) you can set which properties should be updated. This solution is also a lot safer because you explicitly tell MVC which properties should be updated.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I was concerned that I was depending on post values that could be forged for fields that included primary keys.  I'll look into how to use UpdateModel to do as you said.

Comment: You can also attach a Bind attribute to an entity class or a function parameter: http://ittecture.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/tip-of-the-day-199-asp-net-mvc-defining-model-binding-explicitly/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a hidden field like so:

```
<%= Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedOn) %>
```

This would be in addition to your display field.

Comment: Hidden field can be changed on client side. It is an unsafe way.